# How to detect a section in a table view is out of view?

Tags: ios, uitableview

There is a table view with three sections. The last section may contain many items. I need to show a button on the navigation bar as soon as the table view is showing only the last section (e.g. user scrolled the cells up so that the first and second view became invisible).

So basically how to detect that the table view is now showing only the last section and cells from the first two sections are no longer visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITableView class has to methods:

> ```
> - (NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleRows;
> - (NSArray *)indexPathsForRowsInRect:(CGRect)rect;
> ```

Have you tried them? Do they help?

Comment: No because I didn't know where to start. How would I know when to call these functions? The user can be scrolling up and down and I don't want to pull the visible rows with every such movement (if possible).

Comment: UITableView has a delegate method: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath. TableView sends this message to its delegate just before it uses cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to customize the cell object before it is displayed. You can check the indexPath and if it has the indexPath of your interest, you can trigger a method that toggles the button in navigationbar. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, that could help, however it wouldn't be enough to know that there are no other sections visible apart from the last one. I guess I could reverse the situation to show the button all the time and hide it in case villDisplayCell is called for cells either in the first or the second section. That should work...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to iterate over UITableView's indexPathsForVisibleRows to see if the cells in the relevant section are contained in the array.

Comment: Yes, but when to call that method? Every time the user scrolls the table view up or down?

Comment: Yes you are right. But listening to scrollview delegate will help. ((UIScrollView *)self.tableView).delegate = self;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tableview delegate to check which section cells are being created by checking it's indexpath.

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

Or you can use the below function to get cells that are visible and then check for to which section it belongs to.

- (NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleRows;

Comment: As above, I would need to be checking this in real time while the user is scrolling the table view up and down just to determine that a specific time no other sections are being shown apart from the last one. I'm not sure that would be the best solution.